# Unique constraint issue paranoia gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, devise, ruby-paranoia

I have a rails app in which i am using devise and paranoia gems.
I have a users table in postgres db which has unique validation on email column. 
I am using paranoia for soft delete,  issue is when i delete a user and then tey to create a user using the email of the deleted user it throws an error `PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR`.
I have read about this and know that this could be solved using partial index feature of rails.

http://scottsmerchek.com/2015/08/03/taking-the-d-out-of-crud/

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgresql-indexes#partial-indexes

How do i implement this?
Sorry for bad formatting,  typing from mobile.

Answer (score 3):

Because you deleted user as soft delete so that email didn't remove from database, only an user attribute `is_deleted` was set to true.

To resolve `PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR` now you have to create unique index on both field email and deleted_at
So your migration will be

```
class AddUniqueIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :users, column: :email
    add_index :users, [:email, :deleted_at], unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: I am using postgres which supports partial indexes, `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customer_name_index ON customer(name)
WHERE removed_on IS NULL;`. How do i get something like this? What would be the migration?  @Rakesh

Comment: Did you try above solution?

Comment: Could you please explain why you did remove_index before add_index? Is an index added by default?  @RakeshPatidar

Comment: @SiD You are using devise and it added an index to email by default. Now because we are adding index on combination of email and deleted_at fields so I removed from single email.

Comment: I solved this issue using the following migration: class `AddPartialIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   remove_index :users, column: :email
   add_index :users, :email, unique: true, where: "deleted_at = NULL"
   add_index :users, :phoneno, unique: true, where: "deleted_at = NULL"
  end
end`
This seems better to me since in your migration I don't specifically need deleted_at to be unique....this seems more what I required...If I am wrong somewhere mention it, or update your asnwer so I can accept it @Rakesh

Comment: I believe the solution above won't work. See [this doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/indexes-unique.html). Because NULL != NULL, you could insert ("a@b.com", NULL) and ("a@b.com", NULL) again and the constraint will allow it. I think SiD Devesh's answer is correct.

Comment: And also it should be `where: "deleted_at IS NULL" ` not `=` sign.

Answer (score 1):

It will fail on Postgresql, possible solution will be

```
class AddUniqueIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :users, column: :email
    add_index :users, [:email, :deleted_at], unique: true, where: "deleted_at is null"
  end
end
```

Refer https://www.ironin.it/blog/partial-unique-indexes-in-postgresql-and-rails.html

Answer (score 1):

just enough:

```
class AddUniqueIndexToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_index :users, column: :email
    add_index :users, :email, unique: true, where: 'deleted_at IS NULL'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rakesh's answer is wrong and will allow duplicates in the database because a compound `UNIQUE` index will fail when one of the values is `NULL` (and `deleted_at` is `NULL` by default).

To make this work you actually need to use this nuance with unique indexes in the opposite way, you can have an integer column, like `acive:tinyint (default 1)` and a compound index like this:

```rb
add_index :users, [:email, :active], unique: true
```

No special actions required when creating new users as the `active` column has a default value of `1`. But every time you remove a record, in addition to setting the `deleted_at` you also need to set the `active` to `NULL`. This way you can have just one active record and many deleted with the same email address.

In PostgreSQL or MySQL > 8.0.13 you can work without this additional column and use a functional index like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_email
                 ON users (email, (IF(deleted_at IS NULL, 1, NULL)));
```

The result will be similar to the example with the `active` column. Once a record is deleted the unique index will stop working for this record allowing you to have multiple deleted records with the same `email`.